# How to get value from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to retrieve tagraw from storage. [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-limit-grabber/bmjogknbdlfaemcbepmgdaclkdephkac)

I put breakpoints in my background page, but can't see it go in my code.

Thanks for looking. I appreciate it!

------------popup.js--------------

```
 handleClick_: function () {
   var tagraw="";     
   chrome.storage.sync.get({
      likesName: 'yourname'
    }, function(items) {
         tagraw= items.likesName;        
   });
 }
```

----------------------popup.html-------------------

```
<html>
<body>  
<div role="main">
  <form>       
    <select id="timeframe">
      <option value="mustpk">-pick-</option>       
    </select>
    <button id="button">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

--------------options.js--------------------

```
function save_options() {
    var likesName  = document.getElementById('likename').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        likesName:  likesName
    }, function() {           
      setTimeout(function() {
          status.textContent = '';
      }, 750);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

--Instead of using chrome.storage I switched to instead use the new html5 storage.

```
//to save it to html5 storage
localStorage.setItem("likename", likesName);


//to retrieve it from html5 storage.
var tagraw= localStorage.getItem("likename");
```